# How get the permutation of two lists but the elements of each list remain in the same order?

Tags: algorithms

So if I have `lst1 = [a, b]` and `lst2 = [x, y]` the result would be:

```
[x, y, a, b]
[x, a, y, b]
[x, a, b, y]
[a, x, y, b]
[a, x, b, y]
[a, b, x, y]
```

I'm thinking about doing something recursive where I take the first element of a list, place it at the start, then recursively take the next element of that list and shift it through each position (and on each shift go through all remaining elements of that list).

But I'm wondering if there may be a nicer way to do this?

edit: Some more elaborate info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836385/how-can-i-interleave-or-create-unique-permutations-of-two-strings-without-recur/12837695#12837695)

Comment: A simple rejection sampling can be much more efficient than [the accepted answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/104555/) if the sizes of two given lists are far from equal. It is almost as good in other cases.

Comment: A partial [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) might be better, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate a string `chi` with `len(lst1)` 0s and `len(lst2)` 1s, e.g. for `lst1 = [x, y]` and `lst2 = [a, b, c]`, you generate `chi = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]`.  Then you **shuffle** `chi` to obtain your *"characteristic vector"*.  This new list will dictate the order in which to output elements from `lst1` and `lst2`.

I hope this Python program speaks for itself:

```
from random import shuffle

def permutation(lst1, lst2, chi):
    idx1 = 0
    idx2 = 0
    for i in range(len(lst1) + len(lst2)):
        if chi[i] == '0':
            yield lst1[idx1]
            idx1 += 1
        else:
            yield lst2[idx2]
            idx2 += 1

lst1 = 'xy'
lst2 = 'abc'

chi = list('0' * len(lst1) + '1' * len(lst2))
shuffle(chi)
print(''.join(chi))
print(''.join(list(permutation(lst1, lst2, chi))))
```

Outputs:

```
11001
abxyc

10011
axybc

00111
xyabc
```

Comment: I like it.  You view it as picking from two lists and have a binary vector which decides from which you pick. Obvious in hindsight!

Comment: Doing a full shuffle requires `distinct_permutations` from `more_itertools`, just incase anyone else wonders how to do that